# android lunch combo do not have aosp_hammerhead for Nexus 5

Tags: android, repo

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and have a Nexus 5 with me.

I followed the steps from the official android website.

As for Nexus 5 I refer to https://developers.google.com/android/drivers.

I wanna get the latest android version, so I chose the  Nexus 5 (GSM/LTE) binaries for Android 6.0.1 (M4B30X).

and when I lunch

```
gongzelong@gongzelong:~/OpenSource/Android$ lunch

You're building on Linux

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. aosp_arm-eng
     2. aosp_arm64-eng
     3. aosp_mips-eng
     4. aosp_mips64-eng
     5. aosp_x86-eng
     6. aosp_x86_64-eng
     7. full_fugu-userdebug
     8. aosp_fugu-userdebug
     9. mini_emulator_arm64-userdebug
     10. m_e_arm-userdebug
     11. m_e_mips64-eng
     12. m_e_mips-userdebug
     13. mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug
     14. mini_emulator_x86-userdebug
     15. aosp_dragon-userdebug
     16. aosp_dragon-eng
     17. aosp_flounder-userdebug
     18. aosp_angler-userdebug
     19. aosp_bullhead-userdebug
     20. hikey-userdebug
     21. aosp_shamu-userdebug

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] aosp_hammerhead-userdebug build/core/product_config.mk:238: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "aosp_hammerhead".  Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'aosp_hammerhead'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?

gongzelong@gongzelong:~/OpenSource/Android$ vi build/core/product_config.mk gongzelong@gongzelong:~/OpenSource/Android$ git branch fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git gongzelong@gongzelong:~/OpenSource/Android$ lunch aosp_hammerhead-userdebug build/core/product_config.mk:238: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "aosp_hammerhead".  Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'aosp_hammerhead'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

So, which lunch combo is suitable for me to work on Nexus 5 and can get the latest version?

Or, am I got the wrong repo manifest? If yes, how to change it.

Before I follow the steps shown below.
https://source.android.com/source/building.html

BUT https://source.android.com/source/running.html
It is said my Nexus 5 is related to aosp_hammerhead.

I initialize a repo client like below:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync
```

Comment: I think it's better to take this question to different website of stackexchange (http://android.stackexchange.com/ for example) as it is off-topic here, because this has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Got it. @0xDEADC0DE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What branch you check out determines what options lunch will give you.

For example,

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-6.0.1_r77
repo sync
```

will get you the branch for android 6.0.1 that supports nexus 5.

when i run that, lunch then gives me options for hammerhead:

```
$ lunch

You're building on Darwin

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. aosp_arm-eng
     2. aosp_arm64-eng
     3. aosp_mips-eng
     4. aosp_mips64-eng
     5. aosp_x86-eng
     6. aosp_x86_64-eng
     7. aosp_deb-userdebug
     8. aosp_flo-userdebug
     9. full_fugu-userdebug
     10. aosp_fugu-userdebug
     11. mini_emulator_arm64-userdebug
     12. m_e_arm-userdebug
     13. mini_emulator_mips-userdebug
     14. mini_emulator_x86-userdebug
     15. mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug
     16. aosp_flounder-userdebug
     17. aosp_angler-userdebug
     18. aosp_bullhead-userdebug
     19. aosp_hammerhead-userdebug
     20. aosp_hammerhead_fp-userdebug
     21. aosp_shamu-userdebug
```